# CSS Skew with 2 overlays

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate the styling from the following image:

[image]

and this is where I'm at:

```css
.asymmetric {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #7CCBF2;
}

.asymmetric::before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 height: 115%;
 top: -30px;
 left: 0;
 background-color: red;
 transform: skewY(-3deg);
 z-index: -10;
}

.asymmetric::after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 height: 115%;
 top: -10px;
 left: 0;
 background-color: yellow;
 transform: skewY(3deg);
 z-index: -10;
}

body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

section {
 padding: 50px 0;
}

.blank-space {
 height: 100px;
}

h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 15px;
}

p {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 line-height: 2;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <section class="blank-space"></section>
 <section class="asymmetric">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna tellus, ultricies etphasellus tincidunt elit nec. Ornare sollicitudin sapien non, dignissim metus wisi pharetra sollicitudin, sem integer. Nibh sem et amet, ultrices ac interdum, nec enim lorem elit commodo dolor, aliquam ipsum eget ornare nullam, iaculis porttitor. Quisque sint, lobortis rutrum est nonummy, potenti quam quam molestie pede porta. Sem ante dis dui wisi suscipit, eu vitae odio integer, congue velit lectus aliquet luctus bibendum, et facilisis, laoreet ad</p>
 </section>
 <section class="blank-space"></section>
</body>
```

I have tried with `::before` and `::after`, and the results are not even similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a linear-gradient solution without all these markup and less of code:

```css
section {
  padding:50px;
  background-image:  
  /*top layer*/
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 51%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 51%),
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,0.5),rgba(0,255,0,0.5)),
  /*Bottom layer*/
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,red 51%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,red 51%),
  linear-gradient(red,red);
  
  background-position:bottom,top,center;
  background-size:100% 40px,100% 40px, 100% calc(100% - 80px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus est nibh, quis vulputate mi vehicula quis. Donec luctus, turpis molestie pretium ornare, ipsum tellus consequat nibh, vitae consectetur odio mauris sit amet orci. Suspendisse libero metus, mattis vel malesuada vel, ornare eget orci. Sed rhoncus metus mauris, et egestas arcu imperdiet at. Aenean orci orci, fringilla vel porttitor id, suscipit eget nunc. Quisque ac sem ultrices, dignissim massa eu, auctor diam. Etiam tempus tempus velit a scelerisque. Nam dolor lacus, venenatis a leo quis, ornare aliquet urna. Curabitur convallis maximus tempus. Donec ac enim quis ante tincidunt dapibus. Suspendisse et risus arcu.
</section>
```

And if you want it to asymetric adjust some values:

```css
section {
  padding:50px;
  background-image:  
  /*top layer*/
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 51%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 51%),
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,0.5),rgba(0,255,0,0.5)),
  /*Bottom layer*/
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,red 51%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,red 51%),
  linear-gradient(red,red);
  
  background-position:bottom,top,center;
  /*Updated this*/
  background-size:100% 30px,100% 30px, 100% calc(100% - 60px),
                  100% 50px,100% 50px, 100% calc(100% - 100px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus est nibh, quis vulputate mi vehicula quis. Donec luctus, turpis molestie pretium ornare, ipsum tellus consequat nibh, vitae consectetur odio mauris sit amet orci. Suspendisse libero metus, mattis vel malesuada vel, ornare eget orci. Sed rhoncus metus mauris, et egestas arcu imperdiet at. Aenean orci orci, fringilla vel porttitor id, suscipit eget nunc. Quisque ac sem ultrices, dignissim massa eu, auctor diam. Etiam tempus tempus velit a scelerisque. Nam dolor lacus, venenatis a leo quis, ornare aliquet urna. Curabitur convallis maximus tempus. Donec ac enim quis ante tincidunt dapibus. Suspendisse et risus arcu.
</section>
```

Comment: @ZeljkoMarinkovic i updated my answer to consider the asymetric part

Comment: Thanks alot. Did some changes to your solution and came to an answer fro my problem, it almost looks like img that i attached. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replacing your `background-color` properties with [rgba](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp) values (the 'a' for 'alpha' is key here) may provide the desired result. Setting an alpha value determines the opacity of the colour and will allow a degree of transparency.

I've highlighted the changes here:

```
.asymmetric {
  background-color: rgba(124, 203, 242, 0.25);
}

.asymmetric::before {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.asymmetric::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.25);
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/330jv94y/3/)

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other 
resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Got it :)

Comment: Thnx for your answer Frish but my bigger problem is that top&bottom cross sections are on same line while on img isn't like that :)